# Adding the full text of the articles that I manually added to Google Scholar

Tags: publications, google-scholar

How can I add the abstracts and/or the full text of the articles that I manually added to my Google Scholar account?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that, but if you want to deposit your preprints in open access, you should try http://dissem.in/ which allows for easy deposit (e.g. on Zenodo) while giving info on what you are allowed to deposit.

Comment: What do you mean?!... You're gonna add an added stuff?!

Answer (score 8):

The question is somewhat unclear, it seems like you want either abstracts/PDFs to appear in Google Scholar results or guidelines on how to add a missing citation. I'll address both below.

**Help Google Scholar find full texts and PDFs**

You should upload your paper to your website (e.g., e.g., www.example.edu/~professor/jpdr2009.pdf) and link to it from your publications page (e.g., www.example.edu/~professor/publications.html). Make sure you follow Google guidelines:

> - the full text of your paper is in a PDF file that ends with ".pdf",
> - the title of the paper appears in a large font on top of the first page,
> - the authors of the paper are listed right below the title on a separate line, and
> - there's a bibliography section titled, e.g., "References" or "Bibliography" at the end.

Source: https://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/inclusion.html

**Manually add a missing citation**

From your Google Scholar profile page, select "add"

[image: Select "add" from Google Scholar profile page]

Then select "add article manually" and enter your publication details.

[image: Select "add" article manually" and enter your publication details]

Source: http://www.technocrazed.com/manually-add-your-publicationarticle-to-google-scholar-step-by-step-guide