# Manually adding articles to Google Scholar account and linking the PDFs

Tags: publications, google-scholar

Recently, I manually added a conference paper to my google scholar account. Whenever an article is added manually, google searches for it and automatically links the article location. However, in my case, the articles published by the organizer were deleted (probably unconsciously) in the meantime. My question adds clarity to [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/90864/adding-the-full-text-of-the-articles-that-i-manually-added-to-google-scholar/90867). Is there a way to point to the article PDF somewhere in Google Scholar?

PS: I have uploaded the actual article PDF in ResearchGate recently.

Comment: Can you clarify how the answer in the linked question does not answer your question? It points to Google Scholar's help page (https://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/inclusion.html), which clearly mentions what individual authors can do to get the pdf linked. If you have uploaded to ResearchGate recently, I suggest you wait for some time for it to be indexed.

Comment: @GoodDeeds: Thanks, I will wait out till the ResearchGate upload gets indexed by Google. This was the answer I was looking for.

Comment: It is also possible that when Google Scholar finds your PDF, it creates a separate entry. In that case you may need to search for it and add it to your profile explicitly, and if needed merge with your manually created entry.

Comment: Even after several months after having created a manual entry with the link to the pdf file written in the editor field (because there is no field for the pdf), the pdf is not indexed, is this normal?